# Deploy a Qt project on linux

Tags: linux, qt, deployment, qt5, qt-creator

This may be a noob question, but I have been stuck trying to work out how to statically build my qt project on linux. I tried doing what it said on http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/linux-deployment.html , but I do not understand the 1st step. When I cd to the location of my qt project and run

```
cd /path/to/Qt
./configure -static -prefix /path/to/Qt <otherparameters>
make
```

it says no such file or directory. Am I misunderstanding what paths I need to use? I want to make my qt project a stand alone executable which doesnt require the computer it is on to have qt. I have read about dynamically linking the libraries, but I dont really know what to do with that either. The deploy option is greyed out in qtcreator, is there a way to use this?
Thanks

Comment: What you are trying to do here is to build your own copy of Qt (as you should, BTW). But `/path/to/Qt` is really `/path/to/Qt Sources`! So make sure you've got the source code downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

`/path/to/Qt` should be the path to Qt's sources, not your project's. [That section](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/linux-deployment.html#building-qt-statically) of the documentation is about building Qt statically, which you must do before trying to statically link your application to Qt. For example, if you downloaded/cloned the sources to `/home/jxb458/qt5`, then you'd replace `/path/to/Qt` with that:

```
cd /home/jxb458/qt5
./configure -static -prefix /home/jxb458/qt5/qtbase
make
```

Answer (score 0):

Static linking is great when it works, but it can be an effort - I have found especially when using GUI. As Mitch said you need to actually re-build the Qt source code

I made some notes back when I was building statically quite a bit here: [Notes on static building](https://forum.qt.io/topic/57888/solved-qt5-5-static-build-failed-qqmldebugserverthread-run-error-undefined-reference-to-qtcpserverconnection-qtcpserverconnection/3) (derived from many sources) they should at least point you in the right direction - you can probably ignore the part about installing Ubuntu - the notes assume a new install.

However I have more recently returned to the dynamic linking deployment since I feel this is a better way to deploy now. You don't need to install Qt on the target machine you just need to collect the qt dlls and copy them with your application (using `ldd executable-name` which produces a list of dlls you need - but just take the Qt ones not the system/generic ones). For plugins you need to do a bit more (but its fairly simple). I even wrote a bash script to do this automatically (i'll send it to you if you need it), in windows there is a qt script called windeployqt (not sure why there is not a linux variant).

If I where to start again looking into deployment I would go for dynamic linking. Maybe try with a simple project to start with (like a hello world proj).